# Angular8 rxjs6 how to wait for results of subscribe in a service

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am building an application in Angular8 and rxjs6. I am working on separating out logic from one large component into a service.

I am using the combineLatest function to get the results of multiple observables. Then inside the body of combineLatest `subscribe(=>{})` the results data is used to update multiple BehaviorSubjects.

The issue I am running into is that I need to make sure those BehaviorSubjects get the latest data first before moving onto the next statements in the component.

The combineLatest code works fine in the body of the component because I can put the rest of the logic inside the body of subscribe. However, I want to move the combineLatest logic to a service, therefore I need to be able to wait for the logic inside of subscribe() to be completed before moving onto the next statements in the component.

Other similar questions suggest the use of map() or returning an observable of(). However none of these solutions seem to work.

I am trying to return a wrapper function around combineLatest as an observable and then subscribe to that inside the component. However it is not working correctly.

Service

```
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject, combineLatest, throwError } from 'rxjs';

  // Create a BehaviorSubject to track and share updates to People Options
  peopleOptions: any = {};
  peopleOptionsResponse = new BehaviorSubject(this.peopleOptions);
  peopleOptionsObservable = this.peopleOptionsResponse.asObservable();

  // Create a BehaviorSubject to track and share updates to Projects Options
  projectsOptions: any = {};
  projectsOptionsResponse = new BehaviorSubject(this.projectsOptions);
  projectsOptionsObservable = this.projectsOptionsResponse.asObservable();

  getSharedOptions(): Observable<any> {

    // Combine results of multiple observables
    return combineLatest([
      // Get current value of Record Detail subject
      this.getProjects().pipe(catchError(err => {
        console.error(`getProjects failed ${err}`);
        return throwError(err);
      })),
      this.getPeople().pipe(catchError(err => {
        console.error(`getPeople failed ${err}`);
        return throwError(err);
      }))
    ]).subscribe(results => {

      // Get projects select options
      let projectsOptions = results[0];
      // Update current value of Projects Options behavior subject to share with subscribers
this.projectsOptionsResponse.next(projectsOptions);

/* The logic in the component that uses the behavior subjects' data should execute after this is complete only */
        });
      }
```

Component

```
this.exampleService.getSharedOptions().subscribe(result => {
/* Component logic that uses the current data in the behavior subjects which were updated in the service's getSharedOptions combineLatest subscribe body */
});
```

Error message:

```
this.exampleService.getSharedOptions(...).subscribe is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this.exampleService.getSharedOptions(...).subscribe is not a function

This is happening because `getSharedOptions` is not returning an Observable, instead, it returns a `Subscription` instance.

To fix the issue lets change your `getShareOptions()` method like this:

```
getSharedOptions(): Observable<any> {

// Combine results of multiple observables
return combineLatest([
  // Get current value of Record Detail subject
  this.getProjects().pipe(catchError(err => {
    console.error(`getProjects failed ${err}`);
    return throwError(err);
  })),
  this.getPeople().pipe(catchError(err => {
    console.error(`getPeople failed ${err}`);
    return throwError(err);
  }))
]).pipe(
 tap(results => {
  // Get projects select options
  let projectsOptions = results[0];
  this.projectsOptionsResponse.next(projectsOptions);
 })
);
```

And then in component -

```
this.exampleService.getSharedOptions().subscribe(result => {
/* Component logic that uses the current data in the behavior subjects which were updated in the service's getSharedOptions combineLatest subscribe body */
});
```